# Convert strings to time format so I can calculate the difference

Tags: r, dataframe, date

In my dataframe I have two columns with times in format "HH:MM:SS" but in string, and I need to create a new column on this dataframe that stores the time difference in minutes of these two columns.

I've tried to use `timediff()` function but it wont work cause is not a date type, other methods that I saw only convert to "Month:day:year" etc... format, so...

Dataframe example:

```
       Id        time_1            time_2     
        1       "10:02:34"      "10:22:00"        
        2       "00:20:07"      "20:40:30"       
        3       "12:00:01"      "10:15:30"
```

I want something like:

```
   Id        time_1            time_2     difference    
    1       "10:02:34"      "10:22:00"       .... 
    2       "00:20:07"      "20:40:30"       ....
    3       "12:00:01"      "10:15:30"       ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take the difference after converting to `ITime`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df2 <- df1 %>%
     mutate(difference = as.ITime(time_2) - as.ITime(time_1))
```

---

or to get the difference in `min`utes

```
df1 %>% 
    mutate(difference = difftime(as.ITime(time_1),
      as.ITime(time_2), units = 'min'))
```

Comment: how can i get this difference in minutes?

Comment: @ArturBraga you can use `difftime(as.ITime(time_1), as.ITime(time_2), unit = 'min')`